# Visual Studio Check In Policy in combination with .NET analyzers

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis, analyzer, checkin, checkin-policy

We worked before with FxCop Code Analyzers and TFS check in policies.
I can find articles to migrate the code analysis to .Net Analyzer.
I changed a project and the code analysis seems to be working after removing the deprecated FxCop.

**But I cannot find any information regarding changing the check in policies to match with the new .NET Analyzers.** Does anyone have information on this topic?

.csproj
true

```
<AnalysisLevel>none</AnalysisLevel>
<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
<RunCodeAnalysis>false</RunCodeAnalysis>
```

Instead of a ruleset .NetAnalyzers seem to use "Analysis Level" which can not be configured in the checkin policies.

[image: VS Project Settings and Source Control Settings]

Build is working fine without errors and we get warnings due to code analysis. We tried to add a Code Ruleset in the project for the MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset but when we check in get:

> An unexpected error occurred while evaluating the Code Analysis
> check-in policy. The error might be transient. Try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it is not possible to use both features together.

The Check-In-Policy checks (among other things) whether the `<RunCodeAnalysis>`-msbuild setting is set to true.

[image]

Anyways, this setting forces the legacy binary analysis to run.

Reference (from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/net-analyzers-faq?view=vs-2019#does-the-run-code-analysis-command-run-net-analyzers)):

> **Does the RunCodeAnalysis msbuild project property run analyzers?**
> No. The RunCodeAnalysis property in a project file (for example,
> .csproj) is only used to execute legacy FxCop. It runs a post-build
> msbuild task that invokes FxCopCmd.exe.

I think it should not be needed to have a seperate check-in policys anymore, as the .NET analyzers run on every (release, depending on your configuration) build.